# How would I say "this is because," in japanese?

Tags: translation

i just don't think that これわそうだから、 is correct

Comment: The topic particle *wa* is spelled は in kana.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sample sentence and the answer [here](http://www.makocho0828.net/entry/2016/11/16/%E8%B6%85%E7%B0%A1%E5%8D%98%EF%BC%81This_is_why%E3%81%A8This_is_because%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%9F%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E4%B8%80%E7%99%BA):

I am sick. **This is because** I was drenched to the skin in a shower.

私｛わたし｝は具合｛ぐあい｝が悪｛わる｝い。**というのは**にわか雨｛あめ｝にあってずぶぬれになった**からだ**。

For the sentence "This is because ＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊.", the general answer is as follows.

1. その理由は＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊からだ。
2. その理由は＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊からです。(polite form)
3. というのは＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊からだ。
4. というのは＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊からです。(polite form)